# Do Prinny's heal between fights?

Tags: prinny-research-squad

Within the same research effort, if a Prinny fights an enemy and takes 30 damage do they start the next fight missing 30 hp or do they start back at max health?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they do not.

My Prinny, Pricia took 49 damage, then 27 damage in a different fight, and then 35 damage in a third fight.

If she had healed between fights, the 35 damage would not have killed her in the last fight.